# Disable Windows Notifications Programmatically?

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-10

I am wondering if there's a way to programmatically enable and disable all (or even better specific) balloon-tip notifications in Windows 10.

I've done some research and most specify changing key values in the registry editor, however, I'm looking if there's a simpler way using a Windows Library and merely making a call?

I'm writing a WPF Application in C#.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to play the topmost game. Do not play the topmost game: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253